# Apple monitor won't wake up when connected to PC via MiniDVI

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

When I connect an Apple monitor to my PC the monitor won't wake up.

I have an MSI laptop with MiniDVI port and HDMI, both work with projectors just fine, including when using a Mac VGI->MiniDVI adapter that Apple users make use of commonly.

I've verified the power to the monitor works, but apple monitors don't give any sign that they're on at all.

There are 2 cables from the Apple monitor, the MiniDVI port and a Mac power port that appears to be a for-convenience charging cable for Mac's from the monitors power. I connect the MiniDVI only of course.

Is this a common/known issue perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, as of 2016/2017 there simply is no converter from thunderbolt to MiniDVI/HDMI. Therefore there's no way to use Apple thunderbolt monitors by any device other than an Apple computer with a thunderbolt port (older apple devices without thunderbolt are out of luck too).

Perhaps this will change in the future.